# How can I change the "last modified" (or "last changed") time of files on Linux?

Tags: linux, shell, filesystems

I tried `touch -t`, but its precision is only one second: when I use `stat`, I see there are 9 digits all zero after the decimal (`.`):

```
Access: 2013-10-10 15:12:00.000000000 +0200
Modify: 2013-10-10 15:12:00.000000000 +0200
Change: 2015-11-22 18:39:54.369524868 +0100
```

How can I change the "last modify" and "last change" time of files to the precision of 9 numbers after the decimal point?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-d` flag instead.

```
touch -m -d '2015-01-01 01:01:01.123456789' file.ext
```

Comment: how about  the `last change` time?

Comment: When you modify a file's contents, both the mtime and ctime get updated. `touch -m` will alter  both times. When you rename a file or change the permissions, only the ctime is updated.

Comment: @glennjackman I mean how to modify the `last change` time, the command   @Patriceleversque gave is for modifying the `last modify` time only

Comment: Oh, I see. Interesting. When you specify a time, the mtime changes to that time and the ctime changes to the current time. Since the ctime really reflects the file's inode, I guess the OS (or the filesystem) won't let you set the ctime to a specified time.

Answer (score 1):

The [`touch`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/touch) command allows you to alter the *modification* time and/or the *access* time.  You cannot set the *change* time arbitrarily: that is set to the time when you alter either of the other two times.

The reason for this is that `touch` relies upon a system call which can do only the combinations noted above.  The [source-code](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/touch.c#L164) (in GNU coreutils) uses this chunk:

```
  ok = (fdutimensat (fd, AT_FDCWD, (fd == STDOUT_FILENO ? NULL : file), t,
                     (no_dereference && fd == -1) ? AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW : 0)
        == 0);
```

which in turn (see [source](https://github.com/gagern/gnulib/blob/master/lib/fdutimensat.c)) calls `futimens` or `utimensat`. These functions are both [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/futimens.html), which notes

> Upon completion, `futimens()` and `utimensat()` shall mark the last file *status change* timestamp for update.

The *status change* timestamp is what you cannot set arbitrarily.

The two POSIX functions accept `timespec` parameters, which provide resolution in nanoseconds.  Your computer's filesystem may or may not support that (though the result from `stat` indicates that it may).

The default POSIX-style `-t` option is as noted limited to 1-second resolution.  However (still [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/touch.html)) the `-d` option provides for *fractions* of a second:

```
YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:SS[.frac][tz]
```

GNU coreutils supports this `-d` option, allowing nanosecond resolution.  The [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/touch-invocation.html#touch-invocation) for `touch` gives as an example

```
--date="2004-02-27 14:19:13.489392193 +0530"
```

(where `--date` is a long name equivalent to `-d`).